# Rails 6 pass param in render :new after failed save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a standard create method in the controller responsible for creating a new `Transaction` record. The Transaction record has a mandatory `transaction_type` field which I hide in the view and automatically assigning it a value by passing it a params[:filter] so I have one _form for both `withdrawal` and `deposit` transactions, like below:

```
#index.html.erb
<%= link_to 'Add funds', new_transaction_path(filter: 'deposit') %>
<%= link_to 'Withdraw Funds', new_transaction_path(filter: 'withdrawal') %>

#new.html.erb
<%= render 'form', transaction: @transaction, transaction_type: params[:filter] %>

#_form.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for @transaction do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <%= f.text_field :transaction_type, value: transaction_type, type: "hidden" %>
  <%= f.input :amount, placeholder: 'Amount', label: false %>

  <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

If for some reason the validation fails, to properly display the errors, the :new view will be rendered. Unfortunately, in this case, if the user fills out the entire form again (after first failed), the record will not be created because params[:filter] was not passed. Is there any way to pass original params[:filter] directly to the view?

```
#controller
  # POST /transactions
  def create
    @transaction = wallet.transactions.new(transaction_params)

    if @transaction.save
      redirect_to :index, notice: 'Transaction was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I understand the aspect of reusing the view code you really should consider creating separate routes and controllers and solving the code duplication issues by using inheritance and locals instead of by sneaking along a hidden parameter.

```
resources :deposits, :withdrawls, only: [:new, :create]
```

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController

  helper_method :create_transaction_path

  def new
    @transaction = Transaction.new 
    render 'transactions/new'
  end

  def create
    @transaction = Transaction.new(transaction_params) do |t|
      t.transaction_type = transaction_type
    end

    if @transaction.save
       yield @transaction if block_given?
       success_response
    else
       yield @transaction if block_given?
       failure_response 
    end
  end

  private

  def transaction_type
    controller_name.singularize
  end

  def create_transaction_path 
    polymorphic_path(controller_name)
  end
  
  def transaction_params
    params.require(:transaction)
          .permit(:foo, :bar, :baz)
  end

  def success_response
     redirect_to transactions_path, 
       notice: 'Transaction was successfully created.'
  end

  def failure_response
    render 'transactions/new'
  end
end
```

```
class DepositsController < TransactionsController
  # POST /deposits
  def create
    super do |transaction|
      # do something just when making a deposit
    end
  end
end
```

```
class WithdrawlsController < TransactionsController
  # POST /withdrawls
  def create
    super do |transaction|
      # do something just when making a withdrawl
    end
  end
end
```

```
# app/views/transactions/_form.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for transaction, url: create_transaction_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>
  <%= f.input :amount %> # Do not use placeholders instead of labels
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit' %> 
<% end %>
```

```
<%= link_to 'Add funds', new_deposit_path %>
<%= link_to 'Withdraw Funds', new_withdrawl_path %>
```

#### Why?

Because it gives you endpoints that do a single job and it also gives you the obvious structure for your code when the requirements diverge as they most certainly will.

Comment: Ok, I understand and totally support the idea of single responsibility inside of controllers when it's API only (`ActionController::API`). But if it's a typical Rails monolith why do it?

Comment: Why would the app being a monolith make any difference? SRP is just as relevant if not more since monoliths tend to be even hairier.

Answer (score 0):

Stashing the value as a hidden field in the form is the right idea, but you're using two different parameter names for the same thing.

Your `link_to` call passes the transaction type as `filter`:

```rb
<%= link_to 'Add funds', new_transaction_path(filter: 'deposit') %>
```

In your form, you are putting it in a hidden field called `:transaction_type`. Thus, when the form submits the value now goes to your controller in `params[:transaction_type]`. One simple fix is to change the name of your hidden field:

```rb
<%= hidden_field_tag :filter, params[:filter] %>
```

Comment: I would say that a hidden input is the wrong answer 99% of the time and its usually better to create explicit RESTful routes instead.